# how to make clicked text appear on form field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm beginner of javascript and I need to do a simple code for my needs.

1. I have a javascript function dene1() creates text when clicked a button and it appears here

But I can't use this line in below which says DIV CODES

```
<input name="gonder" type="button" value="TL" onclick="dene1()" tabindex="6" style="height: 27px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                Irsaliyeli fatura ? <input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="İrsaliye yerine geçer." tabindex="9"><br>

                <br> <a href="#" onclick="myFunct('DIV CODES')" /> <div id="yazi" style="width: 700px"></div> </a>
                <script>
                function myFunct(the_text) {
                    document.getElementById('yaziyaz').value = the_text;
                        }
                </script>
```

2. My second problem when 
   When I clicked button this function works myFunct and add text into below text area but it deletes all data there... I just want to make it appear after the line

```
<textarea id="yaziyaz" name="textarea1" style="height: 210px; width: 528px" tabindex="12" rows="1">TUTAR YAZI İLE:  (AFTER CLICK TL, TEXT SHOULD APPEAR HERE)

&#9658;DÖVİZ KURU: €=<%=EditCurrency(Round(EURS)*1/10000)%>TL $=<%=EditCurrency(Round(USDS)*1/10000)%>TL
&#9658;VADE: PEŞİN.
&#9658;TESLİM ŞEKLİ: DEPOMUZ. 
&#9658;BANKA BİLGİMİZ : COMPANY NAME 
IBAN No (TL) : TR9245613213465461321
</textarea>
```

3. My third challange is when I click checkbox here it should also add the value to the text area without deleting data there.

I would very appreciate if experts help me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

#### Note

1. You are not provide the "dene1" function, so I write a simple code inside.
2. Just use '+=' instead of '=' for append.
3. I added border and height to show the clickable area.

```html
<input name="gonder" type="button" value="TL" onclick="dene1()" tabindex="6" style="height: 27px" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Irsaliyeli fatura ?
<input name="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" value="İrsaliye yerine geçer." tabindex="9"><br>

<br>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunct('DIV CODES\n')">
    <!-- I added border and height to show the clickable area -->
    <div id="yazi" style="width: 700px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
</a>
<script>
    function dene1() {
        document.getElementById('yaziyaz').value += "You aren't provide this function, so I make a example.\n";
    }

    function myFunct(the_text) {
        // Just use '+=' instead of '=' for append.
        document.getElementById('yaziyaz').value += the_text;
    }
</script>

<textarea id="yaziyaz" name="textarea1" style="height: 210px; width: 528px" tabindex="12" rows="1">
Original words here.
</textarea>
```

Comment: thanks you so much it helped. I did the rest of it.